# Render multiple qml-scenes to 3d-scene

Tags: qt, opengl, 3d, qml, fbo

We want to render multiple independent but similar qml-scenes and use them as textures in an additional 3d-scene, that is shown on-screen. What would be the best way to achieve this? Should we go for multiple qml-scene-graphs or use a single one and update it within one frame? How can we make Qt render the scene-graph multiple times within on frame?
We would like to keep the framerate as high as possible, of course ;-)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: After looking into the code again (from a project not actively developed since years) I think that we wanted to implement our own object picking but ended up using the "default" picking method, similar to the current [object-picker](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qobjectpicker.html).
Before that we actually had a version rendering the scene in virtual buffers not seen on the screen, as having multiple scenes graphs was to cumbersome.